# Why Is localhost not working but folder inside it is working?

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver

Recently i installed wamp for localhost. I want to use `localhost` at `port 8383` so i changed `listen server` to `8383`.

When i go to localhost at browser it shows `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

But say i have a directory named DIR and i have placed index.php inside .

Then when i go to `localhost:8383/DIR/` it shows without showing `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I don't have skype etc. installed.

Comment: Did you mean _When i go to localhost:8383 at browser it shows ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED_ Or do you actually mean you just used `localhost`

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually when i go to localhost or localhost:8383 that message come. But if i change listen server to 80 everything is fine lol. But i still want to use another port as i want to make server live .

Comment: If you want to make the server live you would be best advised to keep port at 80. All browsers use 80 by default i.e. when you enter no `:port` it used 80. If you chnage it people will have to use a port number all the time and that is just annoying

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am forced to use other port. Because my router takes port 80 . So to show my website through internet i should change port other than 80 .

Comment: I doubt it. Try turning off "Remote management" that sometimes uses port 80, but I doubt you want your router remotely managed.